# Characteristic class that cannot be represented by disjoint tori

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, 4-manifolds

Is there a simply-connected smooth closed 4-manifold with a characteristic class $x \in H_2(X; \mathbb{Z})$ such that $x$ can not be represented by a disjoint union of tori in $X$?

I would not know how to prove this without the characteristic hypothesis either so any thoughts on that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In $H_2(CP^2)$, every class $nH$ where $H$ is a generator and n is odd is characteristic.  However, if $n >3$, then such a class is not represented by a torus. It is not represented by a disjoint union of tori, either. For non-zero classes in $H_2(CP^2)$ have non-zero intersection numbers. So if you had a disjoint union of tori, then at most one would be non-trivial in homology (and that one would represent $nH$, contradicting the previous step.)

Comment: Thanks for this example - this then shows that in $CP^2$ there are exactly two characteristic homology classes that can be represented by a disjoint union of tori.  I wonder if there are any such 4-manifolds where no characteristic homology class can be represented by disjoint tori.

Comment: Such a manifold might be hard to find; you can find characteristic tori (indeed spheres) in the only known examples of definite manifolds (sums of $CP^2$). But if your manifold is indefinite, then you will have characteristic classes of *negative* square, and obstructions to being represented by a torus are harder to come by.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Can you please expand the last implication: why must all but one be trivial?

Comment: @magicker72 If two where nontrivial, then they would need to intersect (since any two homologically nontrivial surfaces intersect), therefore you would not have disjoint surfaces.